# If-expression in JavaScript with HTML (optional) button in one function

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, undefined, nan

I'm creating a HTML table with fields, that have to be filled, but I want to make one of the fields optional. My code is something like this:

`name.html`

```
...
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>A number:</td>
    <td><input id="numb1" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Anoder number (optional)</td>
    <td><input id="numb2" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="forfun()"/>
<pre id="result">

Result

</pre>  
 ...
```

In my `jaava.js` I want to use an if-else expression, defining, that if the optional field is not empty, then the variable should take the value of the number, written in the field.

```
    function forfun() {
    var numberOne=document.getElementById("numb1").value;
    numberOne =parseFloat(numberOne); // numberOne is now really a number
    var numberTwo=document.getElementById("numb2").value;
    numberTwo=parseFloat(numberTwo);
        ...


    if(numberTwo==NaN) { //Here comes the problem, I tried also with 
    //undefined and ==0, but after pressing the button, I become the results
    //of my functions in this loop with result NaN

    numberTwo=2; 
    //and so on
        ...
    }
    }else {

    //After I fill the second field, everything here is ok 
    }
```

What should I write between the brackets after `if`? Would you give me some ideas?

Comment: Try  if(numberTwo == null || numberTwo == "")

Comment: Made you a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3xunedL/. Also, don't use tables for laying out your forms.

Comment: Thanks, it works with this +parseFloat, not written before the if-loop, but in the else-loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Comparison with `NaN` always returns `false`, so even `NaN == NaN` will return `false`. Instead use the built-in `isNaN()` function:

```
if (isNaN(numberTwo)) {
```

Comment: better to compare with `===''`. IsNaN should only be used on values that are expected to be numbers. Hence `Not A Number`.

Comment: comparison with empty string will not treat non-empty, non-numerical input correctly. You are right that `isNaN`should only be used on values that are expected to be numbers, but I wanted to highlight what was the cause of his problem (comparing against NaN), and give an alternative to do just that, but in the right way.